# destroy hls.js stream after ui-router state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, video-streaming, rtsp, hls.js

in my app I use video stream. I call this stream from my API and with video tag display streams in angularjs app.

```
<video id="video" class="iframePreview" controls="true" autoplay
       type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video>
<button class="button_pv btn btn-default"
        ui-sref="camera({'streamID': monitorsIds[0] })">
   Recorded Events
</button>
```

and in ctrl, I take URL from API and pass to `<video></video`

```
return $http
    .get(serviceBase + "aaaaaa" + Id)
    .then(function(response) {
      $rootScope.monitorsIds = [];

      angular.forEach(response.data, function(key, value) {
        $rootScope.monitorsIds.push(key.monitor);
      });
    if(Hls.isSupported()) {

        var video = document.getElementById('video');
        var hls = new Hls();
        hls.loadSource(window.monitorsIdsStreamWin[0]);
        hls.attachMedia(video);
    }
    });
```

Everything is working nice, but when I change state in my network console I still see loading stream data...

How to destroy this?
Thnx

Comment: Use [`hls.destroy()`](http://video-dev.github.io/hls.js/docs/html/class/src/hls.js~Hls.html#instance-method-destroy)

Comment: See AngularJS FAQ - [`$rootScope` exists, but it can be used for evil](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#-rootscope-exists-but-it-can-be-used-for-evil)

Comment: With AngularJS, the use of `document.getElementById` is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), a symptom of a deeper problem. Code should be attached to elements with [custom directives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: @georgeawg thnx, this is only place where i use this method... but, if you know how to write directive for this, pls show me. Thnx

Comment: The code in the question is very disjointed. The XHR pushes data to $rootScope and uses data (`monitorsIdsStreamWin`) from the global window. It changes views using the ui-router. It is so tangled that I can't write an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general purpose directive:

```
app.directive("hlsSource", function() {
    return {
        link: postLink,
    };
    function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
        var hls;
        var video = elem[0];
        scope.$watch(attrs.hlsSource, function(value) {
            if (!value) return;
            //else
            hls && hls.destroy();
            hls = new Hls();
            hls.loadSource(value);
            hls.attachMedia(video);
            scope.$eval(attrs.onAttach({$hls: hls, $video: video});
        });
        scope.$onDestroy(function() {
            hls && hls.destroy();                
        });
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
<video id="video" class="iframePreview" controls="true" autoplay
       type="application/x-mpegURL"
       hls-source="$ctrl.source" on-attach="$ctrl.onAttach($hls,$video)">
</video>
```

JS

```
app.controller("videoController", function() {
    var current_hls;
    var current_video;
    this.onAttach = function(hls, video) {
        current_hls = hls;
        current_video = video;
        hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED,function() {
           current_video.play();
        });
    };
    this.$onDestroy = function() {
        current_hls && current_hls.destroy();
    };
    this.source = 'https://video-dev.github.io/streams/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8';
})
```